# Prime ideals in $R[X]/I$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

How many prime ideals do we have in $R[X]/I$ if $I =⟨(X^2 − 1)^5⟩$ ???

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you find out all the ideals of this ring?

Comment: I don't know how to. Any good recommendation for it?

Comment: Prove that all ideals are the images of some $(P)$, where $P$ is some divisor of $(X^2-1)^5$. Prove that the ideal is prime iff $P$ is irreducible.

Comment: I've got that there are 36 possible ideals, but I can't decide which of them are irreducibles ( i've just noticed that those ideals of degree 0 or 1 (3 in total) are irreducibles)